# What is the meaning of %r?

Tags: python, repr

What's the meaning of `%r` in the following statement?

```
print '%r' % (1)
```

I think I've heard of `%s`, `%d`, and `%f` but never heard of this.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Background:

In Python, there are two builtin functions for turning an object into a string: [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) vs. [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr). `str` is supposed to be a friendly, human readable string. `repr` is supposed to include detailed information about an object's contents (sometimes, they'll return the same thing, such as for integers). By convention, if there's a Python expression that will eval to another object that's ==, `repr` will return such an expression e.g.

```
>>> print repr('hi')
'hi'  # notice the quotes here as opposed to...
>>> print str('hi')
hi
```

If returning an expression doesn't make sense for an object, `repr` should return a string that's surrounded by < and > symbols e.g. `<blah>`.

To answer your original question:

`%s` <-> [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)
`%r` <-> [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr)

In addition:

You can control the way an instance of your own classes convert to strings by implementing [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) methods.

```
class Foo:

  def __init__(self, foo):
    self.foo = foo

  def __eq__(self, other):
    """Implements ==."""
    return self.foo == other.foo

  def __repr__(self):
    # if you eval the return value of this function,
    # you'll get another Foo instance that's == to self
    return "Foo(%r)" % self.foo
```

Comment: I've found %r to be useful for printing a string of unknown encoding, when otherwise an error can get thrown with %s

Answer (score 21):

It calls [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) on the object and inserts the resulting string.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the replies given above, `'%r'` can be useful in a scenario where you have a list with heterogeneous data type.
Let's say, we have a `list = [1, 'apple' , 2 , 'r','banana']`
Obviously in this case using `'%d'` or `'%s'` would cause an error. Instead, we can use `'%r'` to print all these values.

Answer (score 5):

It prints the replacement as a string with `repr()`.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `%r` and `%s` is, `%r` calls the `repr()` method and `%s` calls the `str()` method. Both of these are built-in Python functions.

The `repr()` method returns a printable representation of the given object.
The `str()` method returns the "informal" or nicely printable representation of a given object.

In simple language, what the `str()` method does is print the result in a way which the end user would like to see:

```py
name = "Adam"
str(name)
Out[1]: 'Adam'
```

The `repr()` method would print or show what an object actually looks like:

```py
name = "Adam"
repr(name)
Out[1]: "'Adam'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%s <=> str
%r <=> repr
```

`%r` calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#repr) on the object, and inserts the resulting string returned by `__repr__`.

The string returned by `__repr__` should be unambiguous and, if possible, match the source code necessary to recreate the object being represented.

A quick example:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo


    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo(%r)' % self.foo

    def __str__(self):
        return self.foo


test = Foo('Text')
```

So,

```
in[1]: test
Out[1]: Foo('Text')


in[2]: str(test)
Out[2]: 'Text'
```

Answer (score 1):

`%s` calls the `__str()__` method of the selected object and replaces itself with the return value,

`%r` calls the `__repr()__` method of the selected object and replaces itself with the return value.

Answer (score 0):

See [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/string.html#string-formatting) in the docs. Notice that %s and %d etc, might work differently to how you expect if you are used to the way they work in another language such as C.

In particular, %s also works well for ints and floats unless you have special formatting requirements where %d or %f will give you more control.

Answer (score 0):

I read in "Learning Python the Hard Way", the author said that

> %r is the best for debugging, other formats are for displaying variables to users