# Python the Hard Way - exercise 6 - %r versus %s

Tags: python

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex6.html

Zed seems to use `%r` and `%s` interchangeably here, is there any difference between the two? Why not just use `%s` all the time?

Also, I wasn't sure what to search for in the documentation to find more info on this.  What are `%r` and `%s` called exactly? Formatting strings?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6005180/1114171 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/997807/1114171, it is kown as a formatting / interpolation operator see [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the meaning of %r in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354329/whats-the-meaning-of-r-in-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use %r instead of %s in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005159/when-to-use-r-instead-of-s-in-python)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

They are called [string formatting operations](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

The difference between %s and %r is that %s uses the `str` function and %r uses the `repr` function. You can read about the differences between `str` and `repr` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), but for built-in types, the biggest difference in practice is that `repr` for strings includes quotes and all special characters are escaped.

Answer (score 21):

`%r` calls `repr`, while `%s` calls `str`. These may behave differently for some types, but not for others: [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) returns "a printable representation of an object", while [`str`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str) returns "a *nicely* printable representation of an object". For example, they are different for strings:

```
>>> s = "spam"
>>> print(repr(s))
'spam'
>>> print(str(s))
spam
```

In this case, the `repr` is the literal representation of a string (which the Python interpreter can parse into a `str` object), while the `str` is just the contents of the string.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a summary of the preceding three code examples.

```
# First Example
s = 'spam'
# "repr" returns a printable representation of an object,
# which means the quote marks will also be printed.
print(repr(s))
# 'spam'
# "str" returns a nicely printable representation of an
# object, which means the quote marks are not included.
print(str(s))
# spam

# Second Example.
x = "example"
print ("My %r" %x)
# My 'example'
# Note that the original double quotes now appear as single quotes.
print ("My %s" %x)
# My example

# Third Example.
x = 'xxx'
withR = ("Prints with quotes: %r" %x)
withS = ("Prints without quotes: %s" %x)
print(withR)
# Prints with quotes: 'xxx'
print(withS)
# Prints without quotes: xxx
```

Answer (score 2):

`%s` invokes [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str), whereas `%r` invokes [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr). For details, see [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = "example"
 print "My %s"%x

       My example

 print "My %r"%x

       My 'example'
```

It is well explained in the above answers. I have tried to show the same with a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` => string

`%r` => exactly as is

Using the code in the book:

```
my_name = 'Zed A. Shaw'
print "Let's talk about %s." % my_name
print "Let's talk about %r." % my_name
```

we get

```
Let's talk about Zed A. Shaw.
Let's talk about 'Zed A. Shaw'.
```

Answer (score -2):

The code below illustrates the difference.  Same value prints differently:

```
x = "xxx"
withR = "prints with quotes %r"
withS = "prints without quotes %s"
```