# What's the difference between %r, %s and %d in python?

Tags: python, string

Well, i just always use %r on python, but I don't know when I have to use these other formats...

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: That certainly exists on the Internet somewhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986179/python-the-hard-way-exercise-6-r-versus-s

Comment: Well, at least `str.format` is marginally clearer about these.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is explained in [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting).  In short,

- `%d` will format a number for display.
- `%s` will insert the presentation string representation of the object (i.e. `str(o)`)
- `%r` will insert the canonical string representation of the object (i.e. `repr(o)`)

If you are formatting an integer, then these are equivalent.  For most objects this is not the case.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example to supplement James Henstridge's answer:

```
class Cheese(float):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Muenster'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Stilton'

chunk = Cheese(-123.4)

print(str(chunk))
# Muenster
print(repr(chunk))
# Stilton
print(int(chunk))
# -123
print('%s\t%r\t%d'%(chunk, chunk, chunk))
# Muenster  Stilton -123
```