# Python concatenation of string

Tags: python, class, concatenation

I'm doing python programming and this is class unit of that. and the code is not printing the right answer.

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg
    def display_car(self):
        print "This is a "+ self.color + self.model+ " with "+str(self.mpg)+"MPG"

my_car = Car("DeLorean", "silver", 88)
print my_car.display_car()
```

I'm trying to print 
**This is a silver DeLorean with 88 MPG.**

Comment: But what it does print?

Comment: Kaushik, also add spaces: `'...self.color + " " +self.model...'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this version of `display_car` method instead:

```
def display_car(self):
    print "This is a %s %s with %d MPG." % (self.color, self.model, self.mpg)
```

Or, you can make use of `format`:

```
def display_car(self):
    print "This is a {0} {1} with {2} MPG.".format(self.color, self.model, self.mpg)
```

Both versions print `This is a silver DeLorean with 88 MPG.`

I think you see that both versions are more readable than your's with string concatenation.

You can make it even more readable by using `format` with named arguments:

```
def display_car(self):
    print "This is a {color} {model} with {mpg} MPG.".format(color=self.color, model=self.model, mpg=self.mpg)
```

Also, you have `None` printed too - replace `print my_car.display_car()` with `my_car.display_car()`.

Comment: better to use `string.format()` ? and its should be `%d` for `mpg`?

Comment: @alecxe I would like to know my concatenation statement is right or not ? if i wanna `print` **This is a silver DeLorean with 88 MPG** with spaces in them only one after one word

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yup, I've added options using `format`. `%d` might be more correct here, agreed. Thanks.

Comment: @Kaushik your concatenation statement is almost right except that you are missing whitespaces. It's better to use options I've mentioned - less error prompt and more readable.

Comment: I am reader on Python tag (rarely answers as new learner). So I have a question `%s` will behave correctly with `mpg` (auto typecasting happens?)

Comment: Well, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170349/whats-the-difference-between-r-s-and-d-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/s-and-d-python.

Comment: @alecxe Ok Boss I'll take care of It . Thanks Once again.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
def display_car(self):
    return "This is a "+ self.color + self.model+ " with "+str(self.mpg)+"MPG"
```

You see, the `display_car` method must *return* the value to print. Alternatively, you could leave `display_car()` as it is, but instead call the method like this:

```
my_car = Car("DeLorean", "silver", 88)
my_car.display_car()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `print` in `print my_car.display_car()` is redundant because you've already printed the statement in the `display_car` method. Thus, you get an extra `None`.

Comment: so what should i do ? the `display_car` method `print` statement should be replaced by `return`?

Comment: That's one option. Alternatively, just write `my_car.display_car()` (without of the `print` in front).

Answer (score 1):

Python implicitly returns `None` if you don't return anything so `print`ing a function that calls `print` will also `print` `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
print my_car.display_car()
```

should be

```
my_car.display_car()
```