# Learn Python the Hard Way Example 11

Tags: python

I'm doing example 11 on Learn the Hard Way and I'm just curious of how to use an escape sequence for the height part. If I ask for how tall and someone types in 6'2" with the foot and inches as quotes how do I get something in there that will not show that backslash when running it? When you run it the raw input prints out like 6\'2". I've tried a few things and can't get nothing to work.

```
    print "How tall are you?",
    height = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 2):

In this exercise you're asked to call the information you got from raw_input (the variable 'height' that now has a value '6'2"') and print it inside a sentence, by using `%r`.

There are different '`%`' types you can use, and `%r` will give you the kind of 'raw' representation of the string. Zed has asked you to figure out the difference between `%r` and `%s` and `%d` already, so you should be familiar with this. If not, read more here:

[What's the difference between %r, %s and %d in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170349/whats-the-difference-between-r-s-and-d-in-python)

[What does %s mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python/997807#997807)

To answer your question, this should work without problem:

```
print "How tall are you?"
height = raw_input()

print "You are %s tall" % height
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're observing is the representation of the string. Observe:

```
>>> height = raw_input()
6'2'' <-- my input
>>> height
"6'2''"
>>> print height
6'2''
```

When you just type `height`, it will display the representation of a string (i.e, if you were to assign that value to a string you'd get the same as the input). This can also be observed through the function `repr()`:

```
>>> print repr(height)
"6'2''"
```

Or even!

```
>>> repr(height)
'"6\'2\'\'"'
```

So basically, when you don't call `print`, python is basically doing `print repr(...` for you.

---

More info at the python docs for the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) function

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question is:

```
print "How old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh?",
weight = raw_input()

print "So, you're %r old, %s tall and %r heavy." % (age, height, weight)
```

`%r` gives you raw representation of data where `%s` gives you to insert(and potentially format) a string.