# How to remove unwanted single quotes

Tags: python-2.7, quotes

I'm new to programming and I stumbled across something unsightly that I would like to remove. Here's my code:

```
def test1():
    print "What is your name, traveler?"
    name = raw_input()
    print "Hi %r!" % (name)
```

Here's the output:

```
What is your name traveler?
Hi 'Karatepig'!
```

Is there any way to get rid of those single quotes around my name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `%s` there, not `%r`.

```
print "Hi %s!" % (name)
```

I'd add details, but I think others have already written better explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986284/593047) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

Most saliently:

> The difference between %s and %r is that %s uses the str function and
>   %r uses the repr function. You can read about the differences between
>   str and repr in this answer, but for built-in types, the biggest
>   difference in practice is that **repr for strings includes quotes** and
>   all special characters are escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Or use the "new" string formatting method:

```
def test1():
print "What is your name, traveler?"
name = raw_input()
print "Hi {0}!".format(name)
```

Comment: I'd write it `print "Hi {}!".format(name)`, no need for the zero there.

Comment: True, it's a matter of taste. For those interested, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html