# Why does %r work while %d does in some cases even though there is a number

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python Beginner here. Would like to ask you a very simple question.

This is the first sample code :-

```
print "I will \"Add\" any two number that you type."
x = raw_input("What is the first number?")
y = raw_input("What is the second number?")

z = x + y

print "So, %d plus %d equals to %d" % (x, y, z)
```

Using %d in the last line gives me the error :

```
   TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

This is the second sample code :-

```
print "I will \"Add\" any two number that you type."
x = raw_input("What is the first number?")
y = raw_input("What is the second number?")

z = x + y

print "So, %r plus %r equals to %r" % (x, y, z)
```

This does not give the error that the first code gave.

So my question is why using %d gives me the error but using %r does not give me the error ?

Comment: `%d` is asking for a numeric value.  `raw_input` gives you string values.  Adding two string values together results in a string value.  Therefore, you're passing a string value in where a numeric value is required.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for the % conversion types?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354329/whats-the-meaning-of-r-in-python

Comment: But basically, `%r` calls `repr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take input through `raw_input()` , it returns you a string, so `x` and `y` are strings, and `z` is the concatenation of `x` and `y` , not its addition. Not sure if that is what you intended. If you want them as `int` , convert them to int by using `int(raw_input(...))` .

The error you get is because %d expects `x`, `y` and `z` (used to replace `%d` ) to be integers (But they are actually strings, hence the error).

Whereas `%r` which means the output of `repr()` which accepts any kind of objects, and hence it works in your second case, though it would be returning the concatenation (not addition) .

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I get it now. So, basically %d =integers and not for anything else.

Now I have another simple question. When I run the above code and I type the two numbers, I always get the wrong answer. The code runs successfully but the result is always wrong. So if I type the fist number as 7 and the second number 3, the correct answer should be but the program tells me that the answer is 73. Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you read the first paragraph in the answer, that explains why you are having the issue, and how to fix it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used "int(raw_input())" like you suggested and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Every variable has an implicit type that is not declared. A type is a number or string(text). `raw_input` always returns a string.

The `%d` flag tries to format the variable into a number. When it finds text, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use raw_input you then have to convert the strings to the data type you want for example on my example 1 I am converting the variables x and y to data type int using the int() function. Or you can just use input and Python will take care of that for you for example if on input you enter a number Python will assume is an integer and if you type a string then it will assume is a string.

```
##Example 1:
print "I will \"Add\" any two number that you type."
x = raw_input("What is the first number?")
y = raw_input("What is the second number?")

z = int(x) + int(y)

print "So, %d plus %d equals to %d" % (int(x), int(y), z)

##Example 2:
print "I will \"Add\" any two number that you type."
x = input("What is the first number?")
y = input("What is the second number?")

z = x + y

print "So, %d plus %d equals to %d" % (x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I get it now. And I like your Example 1, I never thought about it like that.

Answer (score 0):

per https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input raw_input takes your input and assigns it as a string.

%d only formats numbers.

per https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language (hard to find, %r is not well documented) %r uses convert_field to convert the variable into a representation that will get the same value if parsed.

I believe the + is coercing the two strings (x and y) into numbers so they can be added.