# In python, how to avoid quotes when I print a string?

Tags: python-2.7, printing

```
A='abcdef'

print 'My sequence is %r' % A
```

The output is:

```
My sequence is 'abcdef'
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
My sequence is abcdef
```

How can I avoid quotes?

Comment: Try `%s` instead of `%r`

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how `%r` instructs Python to insert your string with a particular formatting.

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2354329/929999)

To insert a string in another string, use the `%s` option.

Better yet, do:

```
"my sequence is {}".format(A)
```