# Printing statements in Next lines

Tags: python

how do I print these statements in next line? I tried \n but the output is displaying \n instead of printing the statements in next line. I wish to use formatter.
The code is :

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

print formatter  %(
"I had this thing.\n",
    "That you could type up right.\n ",
    "But it didn't sing.\n",
     "So I said goodnight."
    )
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Mac OS, I am using Text Wrangler.

Comment: You have tagged this as python-3.x but your `print` statement suggests you are on python-2.x.  Please either correct your question or retag it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working with `%s` instead or `%r` :

```
formatter = "%s %s %s %s"

print formatter  %(
"I had this thing.\n",
    "That you could type up right.\n ",
    "But it didn't sing.\n",
     "So I said goodnight."
    )
```

`%r`  uses the [`repr` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354329/whats-the-meaning-of-r-in-python), without  formating the special characters :

```
print(repr('\ntext'))
>>> '\ntext'

print(str('\ntext'))
>>>
text
```

---

If you need to keep the raw strings for some lines, you should change the formater to this pattern, and use `r"rawstrings with special characters"+'\n'` to add a newline when you need it.

```
formatter = "{}{}{}{}"

print(formatter.format(
    r"C:\n"+'\n',
    "That you could type up right.\n",
    "But it didn't sing.",
     "So I said goodnight."
    ))

# >>>C:\n
# That you could type up right.
# But it didn't sing.So I said goodnight.    

print(formatter.format(
    1,2,3,4)
    )        
# >>> 1234
```

Comment: thanks , thats because I think you cannot use /n while printing raw data (%r) but what is the alternative to printing raw data on next line?

Comment: maybe using another formater : `formatter = "%r\n %r\n %r\n %r"` ?

Comment: but this will print all the formatters in the next line. For e.g. :
formatter = "%r  %r  %r  %r"
print formatter % (1,2,3,4)
print formatter  %(
"I had this thing.\n",
    "That you could type up right.\n ",
    "But it didn't sing.\n",
     "So I said goodnight."
    )

The below string statements need to be printing on next lines