# Copying paths to python

Tags: python, windows, path

Is there any way to copy a path on Windows that already comes without the inverted slashes"" and come with the normal one "/" so that I don't need everytime to change 1 by 1 ?

If there isn't, is there some way to make python understDand the inverted slashes inside the string?

Path copied right from the **Address bar:**

```
print("C:\Users\USER\Documents")
```

Path that I intend to get:

```
print("C:/Users/USER/Documents")
```

Or even with this double slashes:

```
print("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents")
```

Comment: can you clarify where do you want to copy the file path from (eg file explorer)? The best way to handle file paths in python is through `pathlib` which handles both windows and linux file path including the file name separator

Comment: Gonna look up that lib, thanks! But yes, I intended to copy from file explorer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to handle the conversion from `str` to `repr`:

```
>>> a = r'C:\Users\USER\Documents'
>>> print(a)
C:\Users\USER\Documents
>>> b = '%r' %a
>>> print(b)
'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents'
```

Please keep in mind that `a` and `b` are not exactly the same thing but they both print as string. See interesting [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354329/whats-the-meaning-of-r-in-python).

However, if you need to use that filename as a variable, the best way is to use either `os.path` or `pathlib` which are both part of python's standard library, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html).

You can simply pass the filename you get from file explorer as a string:

```
from pathlib import Path
filename = Path(r"C:\Users\USER\Documents")
```

If you then want to get the path with double backslashes, you can use the filename representation (`repr`):

```
>>> b = "%r" % filename.name
>>> print(b)
'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents'
```

Answer (score 1):

The path that you intend to get (C:/Users/USER/Documents) is not supported by Windows. It is used in MacOS or Linux, as I far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Best format to work in windows is using`//` instead of `/` :

`print("C:\user\USER\Documents".replace('\', '\\')`

Answer (score -1):

By brackets and inverted brackets do you mean slashes?  If you want to get a path from the form "C:\Users\USER\Documents" to "C:/Users/USER/Documents", I would just use the str.replace method.  As in `"C:\Users\USER\Documents".replace("\\", "/")`

Comment: Yes, I meant slashes, already eddited. I'm new in programming so I didn't know this .replace() function. Thanks!

Comment: it's not the best way to deal with filenames. It is recommended to use either `os.path` of `pathlib`. Also, you could have asked this in a comment to the question.